# how to read imported file flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

so i have a function pickFile() :

```
Future pickFile() async {
    FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['txt'],
    );
    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        importfile = File(result.files.single.path);
        
      });
      
      
      
    }
  }
```

i have acces to documentsdirectory with :

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    return directory.path;
  }
```

but i don't know how to put the choosen file into my "importfile" variable :

```
File importfile;
```

i know right know i get the path to the file, but how to i actually get the txt content?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `readAsString` method on file object. There are other methods like `readAsStringSync`, `readAsLines`, `readAsLinesSync` and `openRead`, those can be used as well.

```dart
File importedFile = File('some-file-path.txt');
String fileContent = await importedFile.readAsString();
```